# How can I move vertices in Blender to a precise distance?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I am trying to move vertices in Blender to a precise distance but I am finding it difficult to do so using the mouse. For example, if I grab an edge loop and try to move it to a specific distance, I am only able to get close to the desired distance but not exact.

I have attached an image where I am trying to move vertices to a 10mm distance on the left top border, but the closest I am able to get is 9.97mm.

Can anyone suggest a method or tool in Blender that would allow me to move vertices to an exact distance?

[image]

According to a suggestion, I have used "G", but I had to enter "0.00003" instead of "0.03". Why is that?

[image]

Comment: To move something an exact distance on a specific axis, just press G, then the key for the axis and enter the value, for example, to move 10 mm on X: `G` > `X` > `0.01` > `Return`.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank you, I have added a screenshot. As you can see, I had to use 0.0003, not 0.03. Can you tell me why that is so?

Comment: I was referring to Blender default scene units where 1 unit is 1 meter. In the top left it shows the word "Centimeters". Have you changed the scene units setting in some way?

Comment: Yes, I did. Thank you!